# Ordering mysql query results by location

Tags: mysql

I've a search bar to search for other users by their name or username, and that's easy to do, but what I'm trying to do is that in case more that one user have the same name that you're searching for I want to show first the closest one to you, so that first will appear the users with that name who are in the same city as u, then the same country, and then the rest of the world, I'am able to achieve the required result with multiple queries, but is it achievable with one query?

NOTE: the user table that I'm using for the search contains `Username`, `FName`, `LName`, `CountryCode`, `CityID`.

these are the queries I'm using now:

```
Select user.USERNAME, AVG(userrating.RATING) as Avg_Rating
from user LEFT JOIN userrating on user.USERNAME = userrating.USERNAME
WHERE CONCAT (user.FNAME, " ", user.LNAME) like '%Searched Name%' and user.CITYID = User's_City_ID
GROUP by user.USERNAME
ORDER by Avg_Rating
```

then I use the same query but for the country of the user and excluding the previously used city:

```
Select user.USERNAME, AVG(userrating.RATING) as Avg_Rating
    from user LEFT JOIN userrating on user.USERNAME = userrating.USERNAME
    WHERE CONCAT (user.FNAME, " ", user.LNAME) like '%Searched Name%' and user.CountryCode = User's_Country_Code and not user.CITYID = User's_City_ID
    GROUP by user.USERNAME
    ORDER by Avg_Rating
```

and then the same but excluding the whole country that I used in the prev. query:

```
Select user.USERNAME, AVG(userrating.RATING) as Avg_Rating
    from user LEFT JOIN userrating on user.USERNAME = userrating.USERNAME
    WHERE CONCAT (user.FNAME, " ", user.LNAME) like '%Searched Name%' and not user.CountryCode = User's_Country_Code
    GROUP by user.USERNAME
    ORDER by Avg_Rating
```

and then I'm combining the results of the three queries.

Comment: what did you tried so far? add them into the question. Also add sample data and table structure

Comment: @Simonare I've added the queries that I'm currently using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your current query (called « other » in the below SQL), you want to JOIN on the record that corresponds to the current user (called « me ») and then use a special ORDER BY clause to show the closest matching records first, using a CASE construct.

This assumes that « username » can be used to uniquely identify the current user.

```
    SELECT 
        other.username
    FROM userrating other
    INNER JOIN userrating me on me.username = 'bar'
    WHERE 
       CONCAT (other.FNAME, " ", other.LNAME) like '%Searched Name%'
    ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN other.cityid = me.cityid THEN 0
        WHEN other.countryid = me.countryid THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END,
    other.username
```

You need to replace 'bar' with current username.

Comment: It worked, the CASE construct is what I needed, thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome @A.mode !

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to do this exactly with one query, but you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%searchkey%' OR fname LIKE '%searchkey%' OR lname LIKE '%searchkey%' OR countryid LIKE '%searchkey%' OR cityid LIKE '%searchkey%'
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) you can read more about the `LIKE` Operator.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the hint, I edited my answer.